# Memory corruption with a regular cast? Wrong function called

Tags: c++, casting, static-cast

I have the following small program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    virtual void hello(int i)
    {
        cout << "A Hello " << i << endl;
    };
};

class B {
public:
    virtual void nothing() = 0;
};

class C : public A, public B {
public:
    virtual void hello(int i) override
    {
        cout << "C Hello " << i << endl;
    };

    virtual void nothing() override
    {
        cout << "C Nothing " << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    map<int, B*> map_;

    A* testA = new C();
    map_[0] = (B*)testA;
    B* myB = static_cast<B*>(map_[0]);
    myB->nothing();

    C* testC = new C();
    map_[1] = (B*)testC;
    myB = static_cast<B*>(map_[1]);
    myB->nothing();

    return 0;
}
```

As an output, I was expecting the following:

```
C Nothing
C Nothing
```

But here is what I get:

```
C Hello 0
C Nothing
```

So the wrong function is called: hello(int i) gets called even though it is never called in the code. I understand it has something to do with casts but I can't understand where is the mistake.

Why is hello(int i) called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The conversion between base-class pointers (sometimes known as *cross-casting*) requires `dynamic_cast`. Given a pointer to `A` there's no way to know (statically) that it's part of a `C` object, and therefore no way to statically find the corresponding `B` subobject.

What you call a "regular" cast is the most dangerous type of cast. You should never use that style of cast (at least, not to convert pointers or references). It will force the conversion using any cast it can - apart from `dynamic_cast`. So in this case, it's equivalent to `reinterpret_cast`, pretending that there's a `B` object at the same address as the `A` object. Since there isn't a `B` there (it's somewhere else within the `C`), you get undefined behaviour.

(The specific flavour or undefined behaviour is probably that it uses the virtual table entry that would contain `nothing` in a `B`, but actually contains `hello`, and so ends up calling that, with some undefined value as the argument. But of course, being undefined, anything could happen in principle.)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use C-style casts, especially when working with inheritance hierarchies. In your case, instead of `(B*)testA` you should be using `dynamic_cast<B*>(testA)`, and then checking whether or not it returns `NULL`. This is needed, because C++ compiler does not know whether type of object pointed to by `testA` is inherited from `B`, and if yes, how to adjust the pointer value to reflect that.

So what you run into is an undefined behavior, that may occur because C++ implementation uses either wrong vtable, or wrong offset into vtable.

Answer (score 0):

My guess on what is happening here: By casting an `A` pointer pointing on a a `C` object to a `B` pointer you are accessing `A`s virtual table instead of `B`s.

The usual memory layout for multiple inheritance is

```
+---+   +-------+   +---------------------+
| C | = | A | B | = | A vtable | B vtable |
+---+   +-------+   +----------+----------+
```

Since your objects don't have any data fields but virtual functions they only contain the virtual tables (+ maybe some padding).

Your pointer `A* testA` points to the beginning of the `C` objects memory, since this is also the start of the subobject of type `A`. If you had initialised a `B` pointer with `new C` it would have pointed to the start of the `B` type object. This is what happens in your second part where you convert a `C` pointer to a `B` pointer, which is a valid operation.

In the other part, however, you are trying to cast the `A` pointer to a `B` pointer which is a `reinterpret_cast`. The pointer will still point to the memory used by the `A` subobject.

Now when you try to call the virtual function `nothing` the first virtual function in the vtable is looked up, which in this (as you are actually looking at the vtable of an `A` object case points to `hello` instead. This function is now called without arguments (what happens here exactly depends on the calling convention used by your operating system, but since `hello` only has an `int` parameter I'd guess that this is looked up in one of the processor registers instead of the stack).

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
map_[0] = (B*)testA;
```

has unspecified behaviour, so the result of cast is undefined. This is because classes `A` and `B` are not related, so the only cast of pointers between them you can get is blindly interpreting pointer to object of one class as pointer to object of another class, which is undefined behaviour.

You need to help the compiler a little to understand what you want:

```
map_[0] = static_cast<C*>testA;
```

then you will point to the compiler that your object is `C`, which is implicitly convertible to `B` without undefined behaviour. You *could* write it as `(C*)testA`, but C-style casts in C++ should be avoided because of their surprising nature - as you could see.